# Professors example of `new` in C++ will not work on my machine

Tags: c++, class, header

This is the professor's code:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

#include<string>
#include <new>

int main()
{
    char *p;
    int index = 8;

    cout << "Input how many characters:";
    cin >> index;

    p = new char [index + 1];
    cin >> p;
    cout << "p is: " << p;
    delete [] p;
    p = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

After I **ANSWER** "how many characters" statement **with a number** the program stops.

Anyone knows why?

Comment: You typed the string "**how many characters**"? Shouldn't it have been a number there?

Comment: Please don't take *"how many characters"* **literally**. Take it **numerically**.

Comment: Your professor needs better error checking in his code.  And better variable names to make debugging it more clear.

Comment: The program probably stopped because it's waiting for you to enter the actual characters.

Comment: That reminds me of an old joke about _"Press any key to continue..."_

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you have

```
cin >> index;
```

where you have to input the number of characters.

Then you have

```
cin >> p;
```

where you have to input some characters - but no more than the number you gave before. Are you doing that? It might be helpful to give another prompt:

```
cout << "Input up to " << index << " characters:";
cin >> p;
```

I hope your professor is going to follow this up with an explanation of buffer overruns, input validation, exception safety, and how to use `std::string` to avoid faffing around with manual allocation. Otherwise, you're being taught some very bad habits.

Comment: What if he enters **"the number of characters."** including the full-stop?

Comment: @Nawaz: Then maybe he'll learn something about input validation.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I can't believe I overlooked cin >> p. Amateur hour...